# How to Populate SQLite Database from Text File in Android Studio

Tags: java, database, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqlitestudio

So I followed a tutorial to create a simple SQLite database for my app using Android Studio. I created the necessary columns and variable names and then I downloaded SQLite Studio so I could view my database.

The next step for me is to populate my database with different recipes. All I could find online were tutorial on populate the database through the app itself. I probably want to have that option later but for now I just want to have the list of recipes available to the app on startup.

The easiest way that I've come across is inside SQLite Studio there is an option to import data. So Have a simple excel file to import with all my recipes and that has worked so far.

My question is, how do I reinsert the populated database back into my app so when the app is ran it has the database already populated with the text I inserted from SQLite Studio.

Is this a smart approach to accomplish what I want to do or is there some other way I should be populating this database?

I have some coding experience and work with Visual Studio SQL database but android studio has proven to be a whole different animal for me. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: I went into file explore inside android studio, found my database and save-as to my desktop which I then opened using SQLite studio and made data insertions. Are these insertions being added to my app database in realtime?

Comment: If you pull file to your disk on PC, you're editing that file, not the one on your phone.